# Do bit indices in affinity mask in GetLogicalProcessorInformation and SetProcessAffinityMask mean the same?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

[SetProcessAffinityMask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686223.aspx) WinAPI function has dwProcessAffinityMask parameter, where each bit corresponds to single logical processor in a system.

[GetLogicalProcessorInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683194.aspx) WinAPI function has output parameter Buffer of type PSYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION; ProcessorMask field of this structure is "the processor mask identifying the processors described by this structure".

Is there guarantee, that bit indices in these two masks mean the same (correspond to the same logical processors)?

I could not find any explicit information on MSDN.

Comment: Yes, same thing, assuming this is in the same processor group.  SetProcessAffinityMask would be pretty hard to use if that was not the case.

Comment: `GetProcessGroupAffinity` and `GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx` has information about the processor group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [SetProcessAffinityMask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686223.aspx):

> A process affinity mask is a bit vector in which each bit represents a logical processor on which the threads of the process are allowed to run.

[SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686694.aspx) is not quite clear:

> **ProcessorMask** The processor mask identifying the processors described by this structure. A processor mask is a bit vector in which each set bit represents an active processor in the relationship.

But [GetLogicalProcessorInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683194.aspx) gives better information:

> Each of the SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION structures returned in the buffer contains the following:
>   •A logical processor affinity mask, which indicates the logical processors that the information in the structure applies to.

That logical processor affinity mask referred to is the ProcessorMask member.